# Voltage without charge

Tags: electricity

Can a non-moving charge still have a (nonzero) voltage level?
Basically, if i(amperes, measuring current)=0, does V(voltage) have to be 0 too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current is not required for a voltage difference to exist.  For instance in a charged parallel-plate capacitor, charge accumulates on the two plates.  Even after the charging current has stopped flowing, even if the capacitor is disconnected from any other circuit, there is a potential difference between the two plates.

Comment: OK, so maybe I didn't make the question clear enough.
By "voltage level" I meant how much energy per charge that the charges have at a given point. 
So would it be required for current to flow through the point or is there already a charge there?
Thanks, Alm

Comment: Are you asking about the potential energy of a system of charges and how that energy changes when the charges move to different positions?  Or are you asking about the voltage between two points in space due to a certain arrangement of charges?

Comment: @Alm As with potential energy, there's not really any such thing as a "voltage level": there are only voltage differences.  In practical circuits it's quite common to define a reference voltage (usually "the ground") and discuss all differences with respect to the ground.  However if you have, for example, a charged capacitor, you can use either end as your reference and a voltage difference will still exist.